# Pushing Windows Containers (built with Docker) into Azure Container Service (ACS) with Linus OS

Tags: azure, docker

I have to containerize the Dot Net Core Web API application and deploy that container into an Azure Container Service

Here are the things that I did

1. I did create an Azure Container Service account/domain/virtual machine within the Azure portal
2. Also, I did create another virtual machine for the Windows Server 2016 with Containers that already had the Docker installed
3. On the Windows server 2016 I did create a simple .NET Core Web API application and created an image for that application using Docker
4. I did push the image of the Web API application into a Docker hub and using the SSH tunnel interface tried to download the image into an Azure Container Service, so it can be run from that service

However, I would get a message that the Windows Containers cannot run on Linux as the Azure Container Service by default is a Linux system

Is there a way to deploy a Windows Docker Container into an Azure Container Service
 a. Should I create Azure Container Service in Windows?
 b. Should I use another orchestrator (NOT Docker) to deploy a Windows Container into an Azure Container Service?
 c. Should I go down a different path?

Thank you very much in advance for your kind support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to create ACS with windows nodes (kubernetes can do that).
2. Docker is not an orchestrator. Docker is an engine to run container. And no, another engine won't help here, you need windows container capable host.
3. If you want docker no other way really. Use ACS with windows nodes or use standalone\clustered 2016 Datacenter nodes (you would have to manage them on your own).

I've worked with kubernetes a bit and I believe it is superior to managing ws w016 boxes on your own (and Azure offers a way to create a working kubernetes cluster in a matter of minutes). Kubernetes can do fun things like rolling upgrades, its integrated with Azure so when you create an endpoint it automatically creates a Public IP address for you and so on and so forth.

The downside is complexity. If you want to make kubernetes your production environment you'd better be prepared to fix it :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! Could you please also suggest what what would be better for us to use, the first option or the third one as we already have the containers running on the Windows Servers 2016 VM

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. I did create a Kubernetes cluster within the Azure bash shell and able to run the kubectl command. As I understand for this environment I should be able to run containers. However, whenever I try to pull am image from a docker hub "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?". And I can't find any information how to start the docker daemon so I could run the containers. Am I on the right path or should I not use docker command at all on Kubernetes for the Docker Windows Container?

Comment: try followin kubernetes\azure quickstart guide. on k8s cluster you should use kubectl to manage everything. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-walkthrough I don't remember the exact command, but something like `kubectl run my-nginx --image=nginx`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I did follow the instructions here and created a Kubernetes cluster for Windows where I could deploy my containers. However, after I ran a demo for my manager, I now need to conduct an additional research as my manager has some questions First of all. he is curious why the docker container cannot run on Windows (I do use Docker command when create the container) After all the Docker container should be platform independent and run in any environment, on both Windows and Linux

Comment: Also, I understand that there should be a switch between Windows and Linux when running Docker builds; however, on Windows Server 2016 with Containers there is no docker switch. Only command line is available, is that possible to switch between Linux and Windows modes on the command line and also, just in case, I am NOT working with Windows Containers, I am trying to work with Docker Containers. Is that a true statement that a Docker Container with the .Net Core application (which is also cross platform cannot run on Linux)?